# Relate term to term?

Tags: terms

How can I set a relationship between two taxonomy terms (each of a different taxonomy)?

So, relate a "person" term "John Doe" with a "company" term "Acme Inc"?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it just works... I can use [`wp_set_object_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/) to set a term to a term...

```
$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $bill_term_id, $microsoft_term_id, 'company' );
```

And I can retrieve the company connected to a person with [`wp_get_object_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/) like...

```
$bills_company_terms = wp_get_object_terms($bill_term_id, 'company');
```

The only thing is, how can I put a backend interface on these relationships?

Comment: Alas, it appears not to be bidirectional. When I wp_get_object_terms() for the company, it does not seem to contain the person which had related the company to itself.